# Bokeh. How to match the scale of multiple y-axes?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to draw a line graph with multiple y-axes that have the same scale ratio.
For instance, I drew a graph with a primary y-axis on the left and three secondary y-axes on the right with different scale ratios: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy1BY.png).

Is there a way to make the secondary y-axes have the same scale ratio as the primary y-axis?
I think I should do something with `Range1d`, but I'm not sure...

Below is my code;

```
# figure size
p = figure(width=900, height=300)

# primary axis
p.line(x='date_time', y='t1_posX', source=df_trial, line_width=2, color="blue")
p.y_range = Range1d(df_trial['t1_posX'].min(), df_trial['t1_posX'].max())

# secondary axes
p.extra_y_ranges = {
    "t1_posZ": Range1d(
        start=df_trial['t1_posZ'].min(), 
        end=df_trial['t1_posZ'].max()
    ),
    "t2_posX": Range1d(
        start=df_trial['t2_posX'].min(), 
        end=df_trial['t2_posX'].max()
    ),
    "t2_posZ": Range1d(
        start=df_trial['t2_posZ'].min(), 
        end=df_trial['t2_posZ'].max()
    )
}

# add the secondary axes to the primary axis
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='t1_posZ'), "right")
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='t2_posX'), "right")
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='t2_posZ'), "right")

# plot the data
p.line(x='date_time', y='t1_posZ', source=df_trial, line_width=2, y_range_name='t1_posZ', color="red")
p.line(x='date_time', y='t2_posX', source=df_trial, line_width=2, y_range_name='t2_posX', color="green")
p.line(x='date_time', y='t2_posZ', source=df_trial, line_width=2, y_range_name='t2_posZ', color="pink")

# format the timestamp on the x-axis 
p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
    microseconds = ['%H:%M:%S.%f'],
    milliseconds = ['%H:%M:%S.%3N'],
    seconds = ["%H:%M:%S"],
    minsec = ["%H:%M:%S"],
    minutes = ["%H:%M:%S"],
    hourmin = ["%H:%M:%S"],
    hours=["%H:%M:%S"]
)

show(p)
```

Comment: You are already setting the `start` and `end` of the ranges in your code. That is what controls the range of the axes. If you want the scale of the axis to be different, you need to set the range `start` and `end` values according to your requirements. It's not really clear what " have the same scale ratio as the primary y-axis" actually means. Taken literally, that seems to ask for the extra axes to have exactly the same extents as the primary axis, but if so, why have them at all?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I meant "the same scale ratio" as all y-axes have the same range size. For instance, the range size of the left y-axis is about 0.034 and the range size of the rightmost y-axis is about 0.0116.

Comment: As I mentioned you will need to set the start and end values to make that be the case.